# How to use zeroclipboard on html links?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been messing around with this for a while now but I can't seem to get it the way I want. I basically have a table with links in the rows of a table. How would I get each table item to copy the text that's in the row using ZeroClipboard? Do I really need to put some invisible dom over each one?

http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zeroclipboard will make the invisible flash block that goes over your regular DOM elements and does the copy.  You have to tell it where it should be positioned (there are a bunch of different ways to tell it where to go) and you have to give it the text that should go on the clipboard when clicked.  It will handle all the rest.  The instructions are fairly good if you follow them.  Feel free to ask more specific questions about it if you get stuck.

In direct answer to you question - yes, you do have to put an invisible element over each page element that you want to copy something to the clipboard.  But the zeroclipboard library will do most of the work for you if you follow the directions.